# C++ returning wrong boolean values when in function

Tags: c++, function, boolean

I'm writing a function to check if all values of an array are true. If I write

```
int main(){
bool Janmaat[3]={true, true, true};

int size_arr=sizeof(Janmaat)/sizeof(Janmaat[0]);
bool value=true;
int i;

for(i=0;i<size_arr;i++){
    if(!Janmaat[i]){
        value=false;
    }
}
cout<<value;
return 0;
}
```

value stays true. If I encapsulate it into a function though

```
bool all_true(bool arr[]){

int size_arr=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
bool value=true;
int i;

for(i=0;i<size_arr;i++){
    if(!arr[i]){
        value=false;
    }
}

return value;

}

int main(){

bool Janmaat[3]={true, true, true};

cout<<all_true(Janmaat);
return 0;
}
```

it returns false. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

When an array is passed to a function expecting a pointer, it automatically decays to a pointer. That means that arrays cannot be passed by value. `arr` from `all_true` **is a pointer**. `sizeof(arr)` will therefore yield the size of the **pointer**, not the whole array.

Different ways to handle this:

1. Pass the size as an argument. Chang the declaration to

   ```
   bool all_true(bool arr[], size_t size)
   ```

   and adjust the code accordingly.
2. Pass an `std::array` or a `std::vector` (`std::bitset` is technically feasible too). As this is C++, this is surely the better option.

---

Notes:

- If one element is `false`, `all_true` will definitely return `false`. To shorten the runtime you could `return false;` in the `if` statement immediately.

---

Y'know Linus Torvalds? The guy who invented Linux and regularly insults Linux kernel "developers" (some deserve the double quotes; some don't)?
**[This](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428) might interest you then.** :-)

Comment: It decays to pointer if the function parameter is a pointer. It doesn't decay to pointer when passed to any old function.

Comment: @cad So is the only way to declare the size of the array?

Comment: @Plinth I added something.

Comment: @Plinth You don't need to. `all_of(begin(Janmaat), end(Janmaat), [](bool b) { return b; });`

Comment: 3. Make the function a template and accept the array by reference so it doesn't decay.

Comment: @juanchopanza Regarding your first comment, I added something in the first paragraph. Anyway, whadduya mean with "any **old** function"?

Comment: @cad I mean any type of function.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's probably a lot easier. Thanks!